# How to erase last char of the console output?

Tags: python, console

I would erase from the console the last char I've printed.

I tried :

```py
import sys

print('hello')
sys.stdout.write("\b")
sys.stdout.write(" ")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

to get `hell` but I got this :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried :

```py
import sys
print("FAILED...")
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
print("SUCCESS!")
```

that I've got from this website and get :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

the ",end=''" trick also not work :
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I also found this :

```py
CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
import sys
print("hello")
sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)
sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE)
```

but also wrong :
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `print` add an additional character at the end: `\n` (new line), so that character is what you're actually removing, eg:

`hello` gets printed as `hello\n`, thus `hello\n` + `\b` = `hello`

To prevent `print` to add the new line you can use the `end` parameter, which specify how to terminate your string, like this:

```
import sys
print('Hello', end='')
sys.stdout.write('\b')
sys.stdout.flush()
>>> hell
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not deleting the character with `\b`, you're only backing up by one position and the character is getting replaced by the next position so adding a space would work.

```
print("hello", end="\b \b") # replace default \n
```

Output:

```
hell
```